# Need help on visual odometry formular

Tags: computer-vision, perspectivecamera, slam-algorithm, odometer

Hey there I try to do a realtime visual odometry system for a monocular camera.
Now I'm looking for an equation to describe 3d points movement in 2d vectors. While researching I came across a very interesting [looking equation](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rtc12/CSE486/lecture22.pdf). I'm refering to page 22. It basically makes a simplification under the assumption of a relatively small time step. But now I'm struggeling about the image coordinates x and y. It's said that x would be sth like x=(px-px0) and y=(py-py0). When I understand it right p0 is the center of rotation. But if this is the case the whole formular would make no sense for my case cause I would need a prior knowledge of the center of rotation. Which is based on the translation again.

So maybe can help understanding it or maybe point me to a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use this equation, you must have calibrated your camera (with a pinhole model), so you have a set of distortion coefficients, a focal distance and the  principal point, which is the intersection of the optical axis with the image plane, as illustrated here: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html.

In the equation you mention, x and y coordinates are in pixels **after distortion correction** and relative to the **center of projection**, not the center of *rotation*. So, the px0 and py0 you are looking for, are the coordinates of the principal point, that is, cx0 and cy0 using the naming convention of the link above.

Comment: thank you very much this answers my question. Nevertheless the "standard approach" to estimate rigid body motion seems to be the 8 pojnt algorithm. I came across just afterwards I found the above approach.